# Cygwin Installation: Package: bash; bash.sh exit code 1

Tags: bash, installation, cygwin

I am facing a problem while installing Cygwin for Windows 7, 64-bit. The exact message I am getting is

> Postinstall script errors: These do not necessarily mean that affected
>   apckages will fail to function properly, but please check
>   /var/log/setup.log.full and report any problems." and "Package: bash;
>   bash.sh exit code 1"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/setup.log.full`? What does it say?

Comment: 64bit is very new; have you tried it with 32bit to see if the error is only in the 64bit installer?

Comment: The answer below by user2949130 had solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /dev directory is missing and [cygwin fakes it, which makes it read-only](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-04/msg00345.html). The following code:

```
cd /etc/postinstall/
./000-cygwin-post-install.sh.done
./bash.sh
```

... solved that error for me.

Comment: Hmm -- I get a ___-bash: ./bash.sh: No such file or directory___ error when I run _./bash.sh_